# Why did Rav's family foster her?

Tags: the-tigers-apprentice

In film version of *The Tiger's Apprentice*, Rav has a foster family,

> which turns out to be the primary villain, Lu.

Now, her decision to adopt Rav certainly does not seem to be because she had any affection toward Rav; conversely, to judge from Rav's surprise, her mother seems to have kept up a kind, mundane façade until her true identity was revealed, so she was not looking for someone to torment or instruct in the arts of evil. She also seems to have little interest in fitting in with humans, so it is not as if she needs a daughter for appearances.

And while one might suppose that her goal was for Rav to become friends with Tom in order to give her a way to get closer to the Guardian, certainly neither of them ever showed any signs of this: Lu attacked Tom's house before he and Rav had had time to do much more than say hello—and seemingly because Tom had removed the charms, allowing her to find or enter the house, not because of anything Rav did—and Rav never indicated in any way that Lu had asked her to befriend Tom.

So why did Lu foster Rav in the first place?